# USB external sound card - reproduce audio from multiple services

Tags: audio, alsa, usb-audio

i have an external USB Sound Card connected on my Raspberry and i set it as default from raspi-config.

Then, i have a process that is always running and it use the USB external sound card:

```
root@testsvx:/home/pi# lsof /dev/snd/*
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
alertserv 586 root  mem    CHR  116,5           529 /dev/snd/pcmC1D0c
alertserv 586 root   11u   CHR  116,4      0t0  528 /dev/snd/pcmC1D0p
alertserv 586 root   12u   CHR  116,5      0t0  529 /dev/snd/pcmC1D0c
```

The service reproduce some audio informations when specific events occur.
I need to reproduce an audio file with the same USB sound card with a simple script every hour, but if i run this ile with this command

```
aplay -D "plughw:CARD=Device,DEV=0" -q audio_file.wav
```

i get the error

```
audio open error: Device or resource busy
```

Is there a way to reproduce an audio file with the USB sound card while it is already used by another service?

I use Debian 12:

```
root@testsvx:/home/pi# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)
Release:        12
Codename:       bookworm
```

Thank you in advance
Christian